# Get digital signature lists without open window

Tags: c#, ms-word, interop, digital-signature, office-addins

I'm making a Microsoft Word 2010 Add-In and I wanted to get a list of signatures.

If i do `ActiveDocument.Signatures.Add()`word will prompt me a window to sign the document. I can then browse for possible signatures to add.

But I don't want to sign the document. I just want to be able to display the possible signatures like MSWord does. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the signatures in the `ActiveDocument.Signatures` collection, e.g. using VBA:

```
Sub ShowSignatures()

    Dim sig As Signature

    For Each sig In ActiveDocument.Signatures
        sig.ShowDetails
    Next

End Sub
```

From the `Signature` object, you may also access a variety of properties of the signature, e.g. whether the signature is valid:

```
If Not sig.Details.IsValid Then
    MsgBox "Signature is not valid."
End If
```